# Fetching BLOB data from an SQLite table using C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, blob

I have an SQLite database storing image data in a table.
This table hold image height and width in integer format and Binary data of the actual image in BLOB format.

I am currently using callback function to fetch the required data as below,

```
/*
MethodName      : callback
FUnctionality   : This method is used to fetch the Output data in Collection format based on the Query passed to sqlite3_exec API.
*/
static int callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    int i, width, height;
    
    //Iterating columns
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

        string columnName = azColName[i];

        if (columnName == "Image_Height")
        {
        height= stoll(columnVal);
        }//end of if

        else if (columnName == "Image_Width")
        {
        width = stoll(columnVal);
        }//end of else if

        else if (columnName == "BLOB_DATA")
        {
        **/ *How to fetch BLOB data? */**
        }//end of else if

    }//end of for

    return 0;
}//end of callback
```

How can we store the BLOB data so that we can convert to actual image in further steps?
We are not aware of any methods available to store BLOB data as we are new to this concept.
Any approach available to achieve our requirement?

Comment: How did you store the BLOB data in the table in the first place?? Simply reverse the process.

Comment: I'm currently using the available local database containing BLOB data. The goal is to fetch the data from the available BLOB data in tabulae.

Comment: Don't use the `sqlite3_exec()` function. Use a [prepared statement](https://sqlite.org/cintro.html) and access the BLOB column data directly, by copying it into an `unsigned char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [sqlite3_exec documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html), the `argv` argument points to an array of the results obtained from calling `sqlite3_column_text`. The [documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) for *that* function states that BLOB to TEXT conversion "adds a zero-terminator if needed".

Unfortunately you have no way of knowing how large the value is as it is.
I suggest adding an extra output to your SELECT statement of the form `LENGTH(BLOB_COLUMN)`, which gives you the size of the blob column in bytes.

You can then take the first X bytes of the column value as the contents of the image.